# howto work with ListBoxItems in expression blend?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a question, i have created a ListBoxItem in extression blend, which has a `StackPanel` and this contains a `Image` and `TextBlock`.

the problem is, that i dont know how to set a property to get access to the image and textblock to set it.
i can create new item but how to set the image url and text?

Comment: Would be able to help better if you can provide XAML and the data structure you are binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML needs to bind to the properties in the datasource, and the ItemsSource of the ListBox needs to be set. I include below the xaml and .cs that generates the screen shot shown. I have also included a simple class that contains the data.

```
        <ListBox x:Name="myItems">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding myName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The .cs for the MainPage should include:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ObservableCollection<dataItem> items;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<dataItem>();
        addItems();
        this.myItems.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void addItems()
    {
        items.Add(new dataItem() { myName = "Jason", image = "1.png" });
        items.Add(new dataItem() { myName = "Joanne", image = "2.png" });
    }
}
```

My data object is called dataItem and looks like so:

```
public class dataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _name = "";
    public string myName
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("myName");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _image = "";
    public string image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_image != value)
                _image = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("image");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to ensure that the UI is updated as new items are added to the datasource (dataItem). The images need to be added as **content** and should be **Copy Always** to ensure they are on the device. The finished app looks like:

[image: Phone screen grab]

I hope this helps.

Jason.